# Wordpress - Why if I put the js script at the top of the page it doesn't load?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, include

I'm trying to edit woocommerce settings page, everything works fine in a way, but for some reason if I load my custom js file on top of the template it doesn't load. Below is the template ...

If the script `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.js"></script>` is inserted at the bottom of the page as the last line works fine, but if it is placed at the top of the first lines it does not load, why is this happening?

```
<?php

?><link href="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ><?php

?><script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.js"></script><?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="form-container" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>
    <div class="box-name-surname">
        <p class="form-row">
            <label class="t2" for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <p class="form-row">
            <label class="t2" for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row">
        <label class="t2" for="account_user_login"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="field-settings disabled" name="account_user_login" id="account_user_login" disabled value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_login ); ?>" /> <span class="t4-light"><?php esc_html_e( "L'username viene scelto dall'utente al momento della registrazione, esso viene utilizzato insieme alla password per effettuare l'accesso al sito e non può essere modificato. Se la registrazione dell'account avviene tramite social login, l'username viene generato automaticamente. ", 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
        <label class="t2" for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="field-settings" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>" /> <span class="t4-light"><?php esc_html_e( 'This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="form-row email">
        <label class="t2" for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="field-settings" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <!-- Password Section -->
    
      <div class="drop_btn">Modifica Password<i class="icon_item fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
    <div class="drop_container">
          <fieldset>  
        <p class="">
               <label class="t2" for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password" id="password_current" autocomplete="off"/>
                 <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_current" onclick="showPassword('password_current')"/>
                 <label for="pw_current" class="fa"></label>
                </div>
        </p>

            <p class="">
                <label class="t2" for="password_1"><?php esc_html_e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
                 <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_1" onclick="showPassword('password_1')"/>
                 <label for="pw_1" class="fa"></label>
          </div>
        </p>

            <p class="">
              <label class="t2" for="password_2"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                   <input type="password" class="field-settings" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
                   <input type="checkbox" class="togglePw" id="pw_2" onclick="showPassword('password_2')"/>
                   <label for="pw_2" class="fa"></label>
          </div>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="22350"]'); ?>
```

Comment: You haven't posted your JavaScript code, so this is just a guess: your code is attempting to operate on elements of the page that don't yet exist when it's executed at the top of the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaScript execute after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load)

Comment: Try adding [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer). Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer). It will ensure that the html elements are parsed BEFORE your script tries to act upon them. If the script runs before the page has loaded it won't accomplish what you're wanting.

Change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themes/astra-child/woocommerce/myaccount/assets/form-edit-account.js" defer></script>
```

Notice [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) at the end of the second line.

Another option would be to encapsulate your code inside a function that only gets executed after page load:

```js
function main()
{
  let p = document.getElementById("test");
  p.textContent = "The Page has Loaded";  
}
window.onload = main;
```

```html
<p id="test">Page is NOT loaded yet!</p>
```

Comment: adding defer is actually helping. But generally a script should be loaded before or after the php code ?

Comment: PHP runs server-side. So these `<script>` tags that are linking to javascripts are just static strings as far as PHP is concerned. You're goal is to use PHP to generate a [valid](https://validator.w3.org/) html document on the serverside, and then deliver that to the web browser. Then the web browser reads the HTML document PHP sent it, and finds those `<script>` tags and only then fetches the javascript. @Snorlax

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm still new to all of this and enjoy learning new things about web code. One last question I would have: on a practical level is what I did a good thing or are there other better methods?

Comment: Well, there's probably always a better way to do something, but the first step is to figure out a single way that works, and then refined after that. You've done fine. You learn this stuff by doing it and you get better as you go. Try to find videos on youtube of other people doing the same thing to discover shortcuts and better practices. @Snorlax